# C++ Linked List Initializing

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I don't think it is really hard, however I can't see my fault.
I have a linked list which I want to initialize.
There are two things to be considered:

1. Pointer *stack has to be global
2. Need to initialize (set global Pointer = NULL) with additional function *create*

   ```
   struct StackElement {
       int digit;
       StackElement *predecessor;
   }; 

   StackElement *stack;

   void create (StackElement *anyStack) {
       anyStack->predecessor = NULL;
   }

   int main () {
       create(stack);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Unfortenately, running the program results in:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I think the error has to be in the function *create* - any ideas?

---

Thank you a lot - brain stopped thinking...

Problem is solved by editing the function *create*:

```
void create (StackElement *anyStack)
    anyStack = new StackElement;
    anyStack->predeccesor = NULL;
}
```

Comment: You are not allocating memory, the `stack` does not refer to any object, but you are trying to write to the `predecessor` of such an object... Other than that, you might want to look at the requirements again, as initializing a list does not usually require having a node and a predecessor...

Comment: *stack doesn't point to anything. As David Rogriguez said, you need to dynamically allow memory for stack ie. `StackElement* stack = new StackElement()`

Comment: ...I think I should go to bed - no more concentration left -  thx!
adding ' anyStack = new StackElement; ' at the beginning of the function create solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should create your object in the main function, then pass its address to the "create" function.

Like :

```
int main () {
    StackElement se;
    create(&se);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create the actual stack object. Maybe try this:

```
StackElement the_stack;
StackElement *stack = &the_stack;

int main()
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `*stack` is a pointer that points to memory that has not been initialized.  When you call `create(stack)`, the function `create` attempts to modify the memory that `stack` points to, but you don't own this memory (because who knows what `*stack` points to).

You need to do something like `stack = new StackElement` or `stack = malloc(...)`, but even then I don't think `create` will do what you want: in particular, the value of `stack->digit` will not be set, and your "stack" will have an element in it with undefined value.  So I think something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The global variable 'stack' has been initialized with zero, or some random value. You must set the reference to something or check that it is zero before you use it.

```
struct StackElement {
    int             digit;
    StackElement    *predecessor;
};

StackElement            *stack = 0;

void push(StackElement *anyStack) {
    anyStack->predecessor = stack;
    stack = anyStack;
}

StackElement* pop() {
    StackElement        *ret;

    ret = stack;
    if (stack) {
        stack = stack->predecessor;
}
return ret; 
}
```